# What are the specific naming conventions for variables in bash shell scripting language?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it the same convention as those used in known programming languages such as Java and C? I'm trying to create a lot of variables and I want it to start with a number, but I'm not sure if it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to The Open Group a variable name may not start with a number.

A valid variable name **start with a letter** capitalized or uncapitalized. The following characters can be **letters, digits or an underscore** (`_`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking of just writing the numbers in words.

Answer (score -1):

variable naming convention in shell is `Variable name must begin with alphanumeric character or underscore character (_), followed by one or more alphanumeric or underscore characters.` note that: `Variables can also contain digits, but a name starting with a digit is not allowed` 
see [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) for more details.